EdExcel iGCSE Higher Maths PAPER 2, Q24 - possible mistake?
I believe there is a mistake in the following question which was asked at the end of this year's iGCSE maths paper 2 in the UK. Please read through my solution or attempt it yourself and see if you can spot an error.
The question: (6 marks)
A polygon has n sides, where n>5
The interior angles of the polygon form an arithmetic sequence.
The smallest angle of the polygon is 84.
The common difference of the sequence is 4.
Work out the sum of the interior angles of the polygon. Show clear algebraic working.
My attempt
Interior angles $= 180(n-2)=180n-360$,
Sum of arithmetic sequence $S_n=\frac{n}{2}(2a+(n-1)d)$
$$180n-360=\frac{n}{2}(168+4n-4)$$
$$180n-360=82n+2n^2$$
$$2n^2-98n+360=0$$
$$n^2-49+180=0$$
$$(n-45)(n-4)=0$$
Therefore, $n=45$ since $n>5$
Then we can find the sum of the interior angles using $180(n-2)=180(45-2)=7740$
But, there is an issue here, because this would mean the 25th term in the sequence is $$u_{25}=84+(25-1)\times4$$
$$=180$$
But you can't have an angle of 180 degrees in a polygon! That doesn't count as a vertex. I suppose the mistake could be in the question, and they meant to write $n<5$, but then it wouldn't be justified as a 6 mark question.
Is there something I have done wrong or misunderstood here, or have EdExcel messed up?

Maybe the intent is to show that such a polygon is not possible?

I doubt they would expect that on the GCSE, it’s for 16 year-olds and it’s too subtle a point.

So everything you did was correct but since it is a polygon, you have proven it cannot have $25$ sides. Thus You have proven the maximum number of sides is $24$.
Hence the sum of interior angle is $Sn$ = $\frac{24}{2}$ $(2(84) + (24-1)4)$.
I have seen questions like this come up before. The exam board is not wrong.
